# DB2 SQL Select top x of one column and top y of another column into one row. LISTAGG?

Tags: sql, db2, listagg

Using DB2 SQL, I'm trying to take data in a format like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N | 25 | 300 |
| Y | 48 | 290 |
| N | 40 | 280 |
| N | 30 | 268 |
| Y | 26 | 264 |
| N | 40 | 256 |
| N | 38 | 253 |
| N | 33 | 251 |
| Y | 44 | 247 |
| N | 64 | 236 |
| N | 30 | 226 |

I want a list of the b values of the rows with the highest c values, the top 3 where a = N and top 2 where a = Y.  And within the list, I'd like the values sorted by b ascending.

Would like to get it down to one row something like this using LISTAGG:

```
N = 25, 30, 40; Y = 26, 48
```

Can anyone help?  Our shop is just now turning on FL 501 and I'm still learning how to best use LISTAGG.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  I would suggest 3 nested queries, starting with a row_number window function to create a rank within A, then pass that into a Where filter to keep only rows you want and Listagg that by A=Y and A=N for two rows, then pass that result into a final ListAgg to obtain a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH TAB (a, b, c) AS
(
          SELECT 'N', 25, 300 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Y', 48, 290 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 40, 280 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 30, 268 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Y', 26, 264 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 40, 256 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 38, 253 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 33, 251 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Y', 44, 247 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 64, 236 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 30, 226 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT LISTAGG (LST, '; ') AS RES
FROM
(
  SELECT 
     A 
  || ' = ' 
  || LISTAGG (B, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B)
     AS LST
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      T.*
    , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY C DESC) AS RN_
    FROM TAB T
  ) T
  WHERE A = 'N' AND RN_ <= 3 OR A = 'Y' AND RN_ <= 2
  GROUP BY A
) T
```

| RES |
| --- |
| N = 25, 30, 40; Y = 26, 48 |

Comment: Can I suggest moving that Case logic into a Where clause near the bottom, before the Group By?  I think it would be a little clearer to read.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I think I understand and will give this a shot tomorrow.  Thanks again!